# Type coercion failed

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have something like:

```
class A { }
class B extends A { }
```

Then I'm trying to cast an instance of `A` to `B`:

```
var a:A = obtainAInstance();
var b:B = B(a);
```

To this, I get the following error:

> TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert A to B.

What could the cause of this be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `a` object is an `A` instance, but since `A` is the parent class rather than `B`, it cannot be a `B` instance. Thus, you can't perform such a cast.

If your function returns a `B` instance, you can cast `a` back to a `B`, and access all its `B` members, because the object is in fact a `B`:

```
var a:A = obtainBInstance();
var b:B = B(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

try `var b:B = a as B;`

```
        var o:Object = new Object();
        var ed:EventDispatcher = o as EventDispatcher;//this works
        //var ed:EventDispatcher = EventDispatcher(o); //this causes an error
```

however you may have problems with such `B` instance if calling properties not defined its `super` - `A`

Comment: What for? `ed` will just be null. That's not going to be much more useful than an error.